# Rails :has_many of a :has_one through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationship

I am having issues setting up model relations in Rails.

I have a User. A user can have many requests. A request can have one response. I set up my models like this:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_requests
    has_many :request_responses, through: :user_requests
end

Class UserRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :request_response
end

Class RequestResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_request
end
```

Whenever I try to do something like:

```
UserRequest.request_response.id
```

I get errors that say either the relationship doesn't exist or the column does not exist in the table. Have I set up my relationships incorrectly?

Comment: can you show your db schema for all three tables as well? Just the relationship ids will work.

Comment: Schema or migration?

Comment: you define your db schema in migration files, please show those files :)

Comment: Are you calling an instance method on a class?

Comment: @RubyRacer I think I may be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get error:

```
UserRequest.request_response.id
```

Because:

1. `request_response` is expected to be a class method of `UserRequest`.
2. Association is defined as `request_responses`, not `request_response`, so calling `user. request_response` won't work either.

#### What to do?

call `user.request_response_ids` where `user = User.first`.